# Flutter Add Keytool

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add keytool in flutter and I used below code

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -importkeystore 'C:\Users\MSK\upload-keystore.jks' -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

Ama bir hata aldım

```
keytool: The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
 again.
At line:1 char:1
+ keytool -genkeypair -v -importkeystore 'C:\Users\MSK\upload-keystore. ...
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (keytool:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this problem once, here is how to solve it:

**First**, run this in your cmd (command line)

```
flutter doctor -v
```

this will Show information about the installed tooling.

**Second**, in the `Android toolchain`, search for java binary:

```
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java // this one
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
• All Android licenses accepted.
```

**Third**, copy the path of it until /bin/, in my case I will copy this:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\
```

**Forth**, access that folder, run this command in the cmd (command line)

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\
```

**Fifth**, make sure that the `keytool` command is working:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin>keytool
```

it should list the available commands for `keytool`.

**Finally**, run your own keytool command on that path, and it will run normally.