# Error when trying to run this step in a Flutter project installation

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm trying to set up a Flutter project I found on github. I'm on a step that says this:

````
Run the following command to get your SHA-1 key:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

* In the Firebase console, in the settings of your Android app, add your SHA-1 key by clicking "Add
  Fingerprint".
````

Where do I run that command? I tried pasting that in the terminal in Android Studio and, without even hitting enter, it ran the first line and errored out. The second line was still in the terminal as if it hadn't been run yet. Below is the error I got.

```
keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1                       
+ keytool -exportcert -list -v \       
+ ~~~~~~~                              
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (keytool:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Add Keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74507696/flutter-add-keytool)